# Encapsulate on mvc codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have this verification on each image src from view in my website.

```
<?= $produs->nume_imagine? base_url('assets/uploads/'.$produs->id_produs.'/'.$produs->nume_imagine) : base_url('assets/images/no-product-image-available.png') ?>
```

How can I make my code OOP, dry and use only a $image_variable ?
Also is not a good idea to put this code in controller.

Maybe a class?

Comment: I think I would consider making `$produs` to be an instance of a class with an `image_url()` method that would return either the proper link or the link to the placeholder. If it's helpful, in CodeIgniter you can specify a class that the database queries return.

Comment: You can create your own helper file, with a helper function that can do this for you.

Comment: Hi Jerry, the option with a new class winked me. I wan't to learn to work as much as possible OOP, and I thni this is the best practice. So should I create a new class as helper?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/CHygRfv1 his is what I did until now. Please tell me is if best practice in OOP. If not edit my code, post as answer and I will accept. Also provide me how to use the class. In controller?